# Problems with date dependent value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two data sources one is forecast hours for a job the other is actual hours, currently I have this formula to automatically change between the two data sets:-

```
=IF(K2<='Raw Data'!$A$1,'[Actual Hours.xlsx]Actual Time & Cost - All Suffix'!I84,'Raw Data'!B3))
```

Though currently it shows no value for the current month (i.e July) I have tried the following but with no success:-

```
=IF(K2='Raw Data'!$A$1,'Raw Data'!B3,IF(K2<='Raw Data'!$A$1,'[Waterside Forcast Hours.xlsx]Actual Time & Cost - All Suffix'!I84,'Raw Data'!B3))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `=IF(MONTH(K2)=MONTH('Raw Data'!$A$1),...` or `=IF(AND(MONTH(K2)=MONTH('Raw Data'!$A$1), YEAR(K2)=YEAR('Raw Data'!$A$1)),...` or `=IF(TEXT(K2, "yyyymm")=TEXT('Raw Data'!$A$1, "yyyymm"),...` .

Comment: @Jeeped Thank you your first option worked a treat. Though I don't understand why. Could you possibly explain the difference between my formula and why it only works with the addition of

     `=IF (MONTH(K2)=MONTH('Raw Data'!$A$1)....`

Comment: Comparing Jul 8, 2015 to Jul 3, 2015 is not equal but wrapping each date in the [MONTH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MONTH-function-579A2881-199B-48B2-AB90-DDBA0EBA86E8) will be equal as both return 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of the second sample formula can be described in these three hierarchical steps.

1. If K2 *is equal to* A1 on 'Raw Data' then use 'Raw Data'!B3
2. If K2 *is less than or equal to* A1 on 'Raw Data' then use the external 'Actual Time & Cost - All Suffix'!I84
3. In all other cases, use 'Raw Data'!B3.

It seems like that can be pared down to two steps.

1. If K2 *is less than* A1 on 'Raw Data' then use the external 'Actual Time & Cost - All Suffix'!I84
2. In all other cases, use 'Raw Data'!B3.

The chopped down formula closely resembles the first with the exception of changing <= to <.

```
=IF(K2<'Raw Data'!$A$1,'[Waterside Forcast Hours.xlsx]Actual Time & Cost - All Suffix'!I84, 'Raw Data'!B3)
```

Perhaps you are trying to compare to the month and year (or the first/last of the current month).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jeeped for his advise on this problem. Here is the formula which I finally used which solves the problem:-

```
=IF(MONTH($K$2)<MONTH('Raw Data'!$A$1),'[Actual Hours.xlsx]Actual Time & Cost - All Suffix'!I84,'Raw Data'!B3)
```

Feel free to give feedback.

Cheers